# Buscar apariciones de elemento en arreglo

Tags: c, array

El programa debe pedir las notas del número de alumnos introducidos por el usuario, las cuales pueden ser únicamente enteras entre 0 y 10. Debe decirse cuantos 0, 5 y 10 han aparecido. También deben decirse las notas introducidas que no sean 0, 5 o 10.

El programa compila pero aparecen los números repetidos más de una vez, cuando tendrían que aparecer solo una vez.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

//Programa EJ003
int main(){
    int notas[10];
    int index, alumno, veces0, veces5, veces10, n, t;

    printf("Cuántos alumnos hay en clase?: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    veces0 = 0; 
    veces5 = 0; 
    veces10 = 0;
    /*Se inicializan a cero los contadores que guardarán las veces que 
se obtuvieron puntuaciones de 0, 5, y 10 */

   for (index = 0; index <= n;index++){ 
    //N es el número de alumnos.
    //Repetir N veces el siguiente proceso:

      printf("Nota de alumno(%i): ",index);
      scanf("%d",&alumno);   
      /*Leer la nota del alumno. Si la nota no esta en el conjunto, 
      entonces se añade:*/
       if (!(alumno == notas[index])) notas[index] = notas[index] + alumno;
       switch (alumno){
       /*si la nota es cero, cinco o diez, se incrementa en uno el contador
       correspondiente: veces0, veces5 o veces10*/
         case 0: veces0 = veces0 + 1;
           break; 
         case 5: veces5 = veces5 + 1; 
           break;
         case 10: veces10 = veces10 + 1;
           break;
       }
     }
     printf("Número de alumnos con un cero: %d\n",veces0); //Se muestran los 
     printf("Número de alumnos con un cinco: %d\n",veces5);      //resultados 
     printf("Número de alumnos con un diez: %d\n",veces10);   
     printf("Ningún alumno ha obtenido ninguna de las siguientes puntuaciones:");
     /*Se muestran las notas que no están en el conjunto, que no estar n, porque
ningún alumno habrá obtenido esa calificación.*/

       for (index = 0; index <= 10;index++){
         for (t = 0; t < 10;t++){
           if (!(index == notas[t])) printf("%d ",index);
         }
       }
       getch();
       return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes:

```
int notas[10];
```

Eso está mal; los valores posibles son `{ 0, 1, 2, ... 10 }`. Es decir, **11** posibles valores. Y aprovechamos para inicializarlo, y que no tenga valores *raros*: `int notas[11] = { 0 };`

```
for (index = 0; index <= n;index++){
```

Eso cuenta 1 alumno de mas. Si introduces `3 alumnos`, tu bucle `for` pide **4** entradas de notas. Lo cambiamos a `for (index = 0; index < n;index++){`.

```
 if (!alumno) notas[0] = notas[0] + alumno;
```

No se que es lo que pretendes ahí. Lo correcto es *quitar* el `if` y dejarlo como `++notas[alumno];`

```
  for (index = 0; index <= 10;index++){
     for (t = 0; t < 10;t++){
       if (!(index == notas[t])) printf("%d ",index);
     }
   }
```

Otra cosa que no termina de *cuadrar*. Lo mas fácil es hacer

```
for( index = 0; index < 11; index++ ) {
  if( !notas[index] )
    printf( "No hay ningun %d\n", index );
  }
```

Con esos cambios, todo funcionará correcto.

#### Edito

Que estoy *distraido*.

Aplicando los cambios que indico, puedes eliminar unas cuantas cosas:

- Las variables `veces0, veces5, veces10`, que ya son inútiles.
- Tu bucle `switch( )` completo. Tampoco hace falta.

Y unos cambios menores en tus `printf`:

```
printf("Número de alumnos con un cero: %d\n",notas[0]); //Se muestran los 
printf("Número de alumnos con un cinco: %d\n",notas[5]);      //resultados 
printf("Número de alumnos con un diez: %d\n",notas[10]);
```

Ahora sí :-)

Comment: `if (!alumno) notas[0] = notas[0] + alumno;`
Mientras no haya alumnos al arreglo nota le asigno el valor de alumno

Comment: @AlejandroCaro El código hace, literalmente: `si la nota leída != 0, la sumo al valor previo de notas[0]`. Que, además, estaba sin inicializar. ¿ No te sirve la respuesta ?

Comment: Si me sirve si. En realidad estoy haciendo una implementación desde Pascal y quiero que el código sea lo más parecido al original

Comment: @AlejandroCaro ¿ Y porqué no preguntas directamente en Pascal ? Tu mismo :-)

Comment: Estaba mal la pregunta `if (!(alumno == notas[index])) notas[index] = notas[index] + alumno`; En Pascal es así (no sé si entiendes Pascal) es así `if not(alumno in notas) then notas := notas + [alumno]; `