# Buscar valores repetidos en un array

Tags: array, c

Estoy intentando realizar este programa en C, pero no llego a la solución...

Pedir por teclado el tamaño de un arreglo de números y pedir los valores numéricos con
los que se rellena. Los valores no se pueden repetir. Mostrar el arreglo con los valores al
final

```
  #include <stdio.h>
int arraysize, i=0;

void arregloarray(){
    int array[arraysize];
    for (i=0; i<arraysize; i++) {
        printf("\nIngrese un valor para su array\n");
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);

    }
    printf("los valores de su array son: ");
    for (i=0; i<arraysize; i++) {
        printf("\n%d", array[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("de que tamano desea su arreglo?\n");
    scanf("%d", &arraysize);
    arregloarray();
    }
```

Me falta agregar que no se repitan los números

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Tienes que subir el código que hayas intentado para poder ayudarte @cicaza

Comment: "*Necesito ayuda con un programa de arreglos en C?*" ¿Es una pregunta o una afirmación?

Comment: Conseguí resolver, solo que aún no logro hacer que no se repitan

Comment: Veo que sabes usar el `for( )` ... ¿ y el `if( )` y el `while( )` ?

Comment: tal vez te sirva: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106372/buscar-apariciones-de-elemento-en-arreglo?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente, cuando tu guardas la información lo que estas haciendo es guardarla una detrás de otra en el array sin preguntarte lo que ya había antes en el array. Es cuestión de que cuando lo vayas a guardar, busques en el array lo que ya tienes.

```
int nuevovalor; // Para guardar el valor que queremos guardar
bool encontrado =false; //Para saber si hemos encontrado el valor
for (i=0; i<arraysize; i++) {
   printf("\nIngrese un valor para su array\n");
   scanf("%d", nuevovalor);
   while(j < arraysize) || (!encontrado) //HASTA QUE NO LLEGUEMOS AL FINAL DEL ARRAY O ENCONTREMOS LO QUE BUSCAMOS, SEGUIMOS RECORRIENDO EL ARRAY
   {
     if (nuevovalor = array[j]) //
      {encontrado =true}
     j++;
   }
   if(!encontrado)
     arraysize[i] = nuevovalor; //GUARDAMOS EL VALOR EN LA POSICIÓN DONDE IVAMOS
   else
      encontrado =false; //PONEMOS EL BOOLEAN A FALSE PARA LA SIGUIENTE ITERACIÓN 
   }
}
```

Comment: Ojo con la programación orientada a flags... los flags los carga el diablo.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas hacer 3 cosas:

1. Una variable auxiliar para guardar el dato que vaya ingresando el usuario.
2. Una variable para saber si el dato se repitió o no.
3. Una variable "j" que servirá para recorrer un bucle y así hacer la comprobación sí hubo un elemento repetido.

```
void arregloarray()
{
   int array[arraysize];
   int aux;
   int encontrado = 1;
   int j;
   for (i=0; i<arraysize; i++) 
   {
       while(encontrado)
       {
            encontrado = 0;
            printf("\nIngrese un valor para su array\n");
            scanf("%d", &array[i]);
            aux = array[i];
            for(j = 0; j < i+1; j++)
            {
                if(j != i && array[j] == aux)
                {
                    encontrado = 1;
                    printf("ERROR: Ese elemento esta repetido en el array.\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(encontrado) continue;
            encontrado = 1;
            break;
       }

    }
    printf("los valores de su array son:\n");
    for (i=0; i<arraysize; i++) 
    {
        printf("\n%d", array[i]);
    }
}
```

Por cierto, ahí las variables globales son innecesarias, se puede usar parámetros y queda más estructurada la función.

Además de eso, no es recomendable usar un array con longitud variable, lo adecuado es usar memoria dinámica. Sí intentas compilar este código en cl.exe de VS, dará error.

**EDIT:**

Para no estar haciendo una operación aritmética en cada iteración:

```
for(j = 0; j < i+1; j++)
```

Podemos reemplazarlo por esto:

```
for(j = i-1; j != -1; --j)
```

Y nos ahorramos una subcondición en el for:

```
if(array[j] == aux)
{
    encontrado = 1;
    printf("ERROR: Ese elemento esta repetido en el array.\n");
    break;
}
```

Lo que hace el código es recorrer todo el arreglo de forma descendente, sin la necesidad de tomar en cuenta la posición actual de la variable "i".

Al fin de cuenta, lo que nos importa es el valor que tenga "aux", de ese modo comparamos con cada elemento del arreglo (sin contar con la última posición de i).

Comment: Ojo con la programación orientada a flags... los flags los carga el diablo.

Answer (score 0):

El tamaño de tu formación<sup>1</sup> es una variable, eso hace que tu formación sea una Formación de Tamaño Variable (Variable Length Array en inglés) y eso no está permitido en C moderno, lee [estas preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vla+%5Bc%5D) para saber más del tema.

Si quieres pedir un tamaño y usarlo para crear una formación de valores, deberás usar `malloc`:

```
int *array (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * arraysize);
```

No olvides que cuando ya no necesites la memoria, deberás liberarla con `free`:

```
free(array);
```

---

Si quieres rellenar una formación con datos que no se repitan, te aconsejo redactar una función que busque si un número está presente en una formación:

```
int busca_numero_en(int *inicio, int *fin, int numero) {
    for (; inicio != fin; ++inicio)
        if (*inicio == numero)
            return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Sabiendo si un número ya está en la formación, sabrás si debes o no insertarlo:

```
for (int indice = 0; indice < arraysize; ) {
    int numero;
    printf("Ingrese un valor:\n");
    scanf("%d", &numero);

    if (busca_numero_en(array, array + indice, numero) == 0) {
        array[indice] = numero;
        ++indice
    }
    else
        printf("Numero repetido\n");
}
```

Fíjate que sólo buscamos repeticiones entre los números ya guardados (ahorrándonos buscar donde sabemos que no debemos buscar), observa también que sólo aumentamos el índice cuando se guarda un número. Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CIHBLQMzMuAov9D1).

---

1. También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.